# Show pop-up message

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this overlay (I hope it's an overlay :) pop-up message from the bootstrap framework.

```
<div class="toast" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
  <div class="toast-header">
    <img src="..." class="rounded mr-2" alt="...">
    <strong class="mr-auto">Bootstrap</strong>
    <small>11 mins ago</small>
    <button type="button" class="ml-2 mb-1 close" data-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="toast-body">
    Record Added!
  </div>
</div>
```

Can someone help me to show this message for 4 sec after the record was added?

this is my function that adds the record

```
function addNewRow(rowData) {
    const currentDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+2", "dd.MM.yy");
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const ws = ss.getSheetByName('Data');
ws.appendRow([currentDate,rowData.docnumber1,rowData.whereandhow1,rowData.comment1,rowData.incomeeur1,rowData.incomeusd1,rowData.incomeuah1,rowData.eurrate1,rowData.usdrate1,rowData.expenseeur1,rowData.expenseusd1,rowData.expenseuah1,rowData.expensetype1]);
return true;
}
```

also this is the link for my spreassheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AWUoP-xfNYhn9AnztlaXkf2CivyuqALCekgQDfxFPk4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: How are you displaying the pop-up, through HTML Service?

Comment: actually, I don't even know how. I edited this code https://youtu.be/yvDX_ZbWvyA?t=678
but somehow I didn't manage to do this message, so I gave up, and now I really need it to be shown

here is the link for my sheet. maybe you can see the code https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AWUoP-xfNYhn9AnztlaXkf2CivyuqALCekgQDfxFPk4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Try [spreadsheet.toast()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#parseCsv(String))

Comment: I didn't watch the whole video because most of it is unrelated to your question.  I'm still not sure what you want.  You create a sidebar and I guess process some input from the user.  At some point on the sidebar the user requests to add a row.  Now you want a pop-up to appear, say "Record Added!" and remain visible for 5 seconds?  As that what you want?

Comment: Yes, when user clicked the button, his record populates the spreadsheet. After it was done, he should see the confirmation "Record Added!"

Answer (score 2):

Simple Popup

```
function mypopup(msg="My Message") {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(`<textarea>${msg}</textarea>`),"My Popup");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an simple example of how to have a pop up appear with the sidebar active.

**Code.gs**

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("Test");
  menu.addItem("Show Test","showTest");
  menu.addToUi();
}

function showTest() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("HTML_Sidebar");
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}

function addNewRow(rowData) {
  // do your stuff
  let html =  HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("HTML_Popup");
  html.setHeight(10);
  html.setWidth(200);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html,"Record Added!");
}
```

**HTML_Sidebar**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Add row data</p>
    <input type="text" id="rowData">
    <input type="button" value="Add a row" onclick="addRowOnClick()">
    <script>
      function addRowOnClick() {
        try {
          let rowData = document.getElementById("rowData").value;
          google.script.run.addNewRow(rowData);
        }
        catch(err) {
          alert(err);
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**HTML_Popup**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      ( function () {
          try {
            let time = new Date();
            time = time.valueOf();
            let stop = time+4000;  // add 4 seconds
            while( time < stop ) {
              time = new Date();
              time = time.valueOf();
            }
            google.script.host.close();
          }
          catch(err) {
            alert(err);
          }
        }
      )();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Results**

[image]

Comment: I'm not good at coding, I must have done something wrong. 
I've got an error TypeError: google.script.host.close is not a function

Comment: Do you have the parenthesis at the end `google.script.host.close()`?

Comment: yes, I did copy your code

Comment: You copied my code exactly as a test project?  Because my screen shot shows it works.

Comment: I copied this into my project. 
I'm not so educated about scripts. I managed to change the whole script for my needs, I watched a lot of videos but the message is beyond my powers :)

Comment: Maybe update your post with the latest code.